# vuejs this is undefined in my eventListner

Tags: vue.js

I've tried to make a google map in vuejs where the value of the center of my map is shown in my view.

For this, I created my marker and tried to  update the value with `this.marker = map.center.lng();` or `this.setMarkerLng(map.center.lng());` inside an event listner of my method Initmap but none of them work. I got the message:

> this is undefined

Outside the eventlistener, everything works.

Can you help?

```
export default {
        mounted: function () {
            this.initMap();
        },
        data() {
            return {
                marker: {
                    lng : 'latitude',
                    lat: 'longitude'
                        }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            ///google map init
            initMap() {
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: {lat: 48.587536, lng: 7.751440},
                    zoom: 13
                });

                this.setMarkerLat(map.center.lat());
                this.setMarkerLng(map.center.lng());

                ///Listner
                autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {

                    ///call method bug
                    this.setMarkerLat(map.center.lat());
                    this.setMarkerLng(map.center.lng());

                    infowindow.close();
                      this.marker.lat = map.center.lat();
                      this.marker.lng = map.center.lng();
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                    if (!place.geometry) {

                        window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
                        return;
                    }

                    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
                    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                    } else {
                        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                        map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
                    }
                    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
                    marker.setVisible(true);


                    var address = '';
                    if (place.address_components) {
                        address = [
                            (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                            (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                            (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                        ].join(' ');
                    }
            },
            setMarkerLng: function(lng) {
                this.marker.lng = lng;
            },
            setMarkerLat: function(lat){
                this.marker.lat = lat;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to bind `autocomplete` value to some prop, like `place`, then watch this prop and  dispatch the function that you put inside `place_changed` event. Move the code executed inside `place_changed` event to a method that you will call when ` place `prop` change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the arrow function `()=>` in order to be able to access `this` scope like :

```
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', ()=> {
  ...
 }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot !! so i need to use arrow if i want to scope the vue object ?

Comment: yes, or you should assign `this` to a global variable and access that variable inside callback function